# Bluetooth LE restricting availability in Play Store

Tags: android

My app uses Bluetooth LE but it's not required, I've added:

```
 <uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
  android:required="false" />
```

Into the manifest but I'm still seeing it listed as a feature when uploading the apk to play store.

Eligibility of devices has plummeted since adding this permission and not sure if this is a bug in the android framework or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my issue was with the Estimote SDK, I found this line in the document:

> Android Estimote SDK requires certain permissions in order to function
>   properly. Luckily, there’s no extra steps you need to take here. The
>   permissions are defined in the SDK’s manifest file and are
>   automatically merged into your app’s AndroidManifest.xml, so you don’t
>   need to declare them by hand.

So I decided to upgrade the library to the latest version and now my app doesn't require the Bluetooth LE feature.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are doing it correctly by declaring it in your manifest

```
 <uses-feature
 android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
 android:required="false" />
```

then using a block like this when you need to use the capability.

```
// Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device. Then
// you can selectively disable BLE-related features.
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)  {
  Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  finish();
}
```

Seems like it's treating it like you put in true.  Do you have any other manifests declared that are maybe being merged together and fouling the result manifest?

Comment: I just had a thought, we use Estimote for our beacons so I went back to the documentation and came across this line: "Android Estimote SDK requires certain permissions in order to function properly. Luckily, there’s no extra steps you need to take here. The permissions are defined in the SDK’s manifest file and are automatically merged into your app’s AndroidManifest.xml, so you don’t need to declare them by hand." So this is what could potentially be causing the issue. I'll look into it some more.

Comment: I guess I was on the right track with the manifest merging then. Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Yeah it was definitely your answer that led me in the right direction so thanks for that :)